# Plugin list-category-posts - How can I use "id" or "name" parameters?

Tags: plugin-list-category-post

In "list-category-post", the shortcode parameter options [catlist **id=1,2,3**],[catlist **id=-99**],[catlist **name='TestCategory'**] don't work correctly.

It always shows posts from **All categories**.

How do I use "id" or "name" option? All other options are shown correctly.
My WordPress version is 3.3.1 and I use twentyten theme.

My code is below:

```
[catlist id=-1,-2,-3 thumbnail=yes thumbnail_size=thumbnail orderby=date order=DESC numberposts=10 date=yes author=yes excerpt=yes excludeposts=999,1000,1001 content=no catlink=yes comments=yes morelink="Read more" categorypage=yes post_type=post]
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two conflicting parameters in your shortcode:

> **categorypage** - Set it to "yes" if you want to list the posts from the current post's category.

And

> **id** - To display posts from a category using the category's id. Ex: [catlist id=24]. You can include several categories: Ex: [catlist
>   id=17,24,32] or exclude a category with the minus (-)

Comment: Glad I helped! If it worked correctly, you can mark this answer as correct.